# Distance between a compact closed body and its convex hull

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Given any compact closed body $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be its convex hull.

Is there any theories regarding the distance between S and K? Also are there any regarding how well does $K$ approximates $S$ e.g. by volume.

Regarding distance, I interested in finding the maximal distance between a boundary point in $S$ and it's corresponding point (closest point) on the boundary of the convex hull $K$.

Please advise.

Comment: The distance is always zero (since the two sets always overlap), and the volume expansion can be infinite when considering the convex hull of a finite set of points (which has zero volume).

Comment: I will edit the question since i was not clear enough.

Comment: What does "corresponding point" mean? Do you mean the closest point?

Comment: Exactly. (edits has been done in light of your comment :) )

Comment: You should look at saddle point and minmax theory